# Sharing a Visual Studio Project that requires External Libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am not a developer that does C++ professionally or programs using Visual Studio professionally. Hopefully this question isn't too trivial.

The standard way to include external libraries is to link them in your project settings. However suppose I want to share this project with a few coworkers, or a friend. Obviously they will need these required libraries as well.

In CMake there are modules to detect and load libraries that are available on the system in a path-independent way. In otherwords, by the virtue of cmake finding the library, it will put the right paths for the headers and other required things in the configured solution *automagically*.

Certain things in CMake are made more complicated and slow down development - for example including and managing resource files. As a result I'd like to ditch CMake for standard MSBuild Visual Studio. My only hangup is how do I create my solution file in such a way the next person to compile my code doesn't require the libraries to be in the exact same place as me? Do they have to just configure the solution themselves when they load it? What is the standard practice here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*" As a result I'd like to ditch CMake for standard MSBuild Visual Studio. My only hangup is how do I create my solution file in such a way the next person to compile my code doesn't require the libraries to be in the exact same place as me? Do they have to just configure the solution themselves when they load it? What is the standard practice here."*

Depends. When the external lib can be fetched from NuGet, it is easy. Just let VS restore any dependencies on the first build. Files will land in Solution\packages.

If there are DLL's with source code to be added into the solution, specific to your project, you can include them in a Solution\Subdir and their target DLL and LIB will end up in Solution\Debug or \x64\Debug.

If there are external DLL's without sources in the solution, it seems logical to put them in \Debug or \x64\Debug.

Sometimes you can't recompile or move DLL stuff.. In that case, go right click your Project in Solution, menu Properties, choose Configuration, Linker, General and Input.. there, you can specify additional library subdirectories and additional libraries.

Closing tip: about this *"configure the solution"* remark .. you come from a CMake world, you're used to edit configuation stuff by hand. Don't bother about that in VS. Leave .sln internals to VS, just use the VS-2017 UI to maintain things.

Answer (score 0):

We use the MSBuild support for props files.

props file (e.g. envdeppaths.x64.user.props containing paths to libraries):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ...>
  <PropertyGroup Label="EnvDependentPaths">
    <!-- base directory of boost to be used -->
    <BoostDir>c:\dev\libs\boost</BoostDir>
    ...
```

These files contain the library paths (headers and binaries separate in some cases),
preprocessor defines needed, etc.

They are imported in the project files similar to this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ...
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ImportGroup Label="EnvDependentPaths">
      <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\envdeppaths.$(Platform).user.props" 
              Condition="exists('$(SolutionDir)\envdeppaths.$(Platform).user.props')" 
              Label="EnvDependentPaths" />
    </ImportGroup>
    ...
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
      <ClCompile>
        <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
     <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(BoostDir);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
     ...
```

There are a few downsides to this approach, though:

- manually editing of project files required
- props files cannot be simply checked into VCS, so clean checkout needs manual placement of props files

Certainly there are other ways. Visual Studio contains an editor for the build properties in the configuration manager without manual editing required.

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen done in several places, is putting the libraries as part of the project in Source Control, under a separate folder, e.g. /extern/.

Then you use relative path in your include and lib dirs setting for your project to refer to this extern path

This way you get good control over which versions of the libraries the project is compiled against, and integration of newer versions can be a single submit in your source control repository.